# How to get conditional One-To-Many

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Scenario:

```
PARENT  1.\*  CHILDREN
```

In "one to many", using annotation I fetch all the children of a parent. OK... Now children have filed *gender(f/m)*. I want that whenever I get the parent object I may get only female or male. How to apply the condition with *oneToMany* in this scenario...?

Comment: Do you know about a third gender?

Comment: Yes "Adam Arold" @AdamArold :)

Comment: (Off-topic: Quite often, children *don't* have exactly 1 parent, so strictly speaking we're not talking about a 1:N relationship.)

Answer (score 0):

How about using Hibernate filters http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#filters. First define filters for your entities and then enable/disable them where you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some hql like this:

```
from Parent left outer join children c where c.male=MALE
```